# How to display the historgram of pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I use my code to group and agg a pyspark dataframe, it looks like:

```
>>> df.groupBy('DAY_OF_WEEK','confirmed').agg(F.count('confirmed').alias('count')).sort('DAY_OF_WEEK').show()

+-----------+---------+-----+
|DAY_OF_WEEK|Confirmed|count|
+-----------+---------+-----+
|          1|        0|19281|
|          1|        1|10292|
|          2|        1|91010|
|          2|        0|59129|
|          3|        1|40128|
|          3|        0|38281|
+-----------+---------+-----+
```

Is there any way to plot the histogram of this pyspark dataframe? I can only plot that by converting it to pandas dataframe, but I am trying to find a function can apply to pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot visualize with Spark directly.